# fetch different keys with different attributes(params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def appliance_params
  params.require(:tv).permit(:x, y:, :z)
end
```

In this example I receive a key 'tv' and the values x, y, and z.

How can I modify this function to receive different keys ?

This function can receive different appliances, I can receive a :iron, a :computer etc... with different values.

I will only receive one appliance in params.

Comment: what you want to receive?

Answer (score 0):

```
def appliance_params
  params.require(:tv).permit(:x, :y, :z)
end
```

is specific for a tv model.

to get any other params use:

`params[:iron]`

or if the iron param is part of the tv take it in the permit call:

```
def appliance_params
  params.require(:tv).permit(:x, :y, :z, :iron)
end
```

Comment: yes, but this controller is for multiple models. params.require(:tv), params.require(:iron) etc...

Comment: then you should obviously create a second controller called `IronsController` (RESTfulness!)
Or do it dirty:
`def iron_params;
  params.require(:iron).permit(:whatever...);
end`